# Configuration and hardware for custom office networking

Tags: router, qos

First of all I am not a professional in the field of networking. I only have a CCNA level 1 and I am very familiar to home use routers & Linux administration.

I have to configure the fallowing setup and I am not sure this could be done with a common router.

Location has **1 physical internet connection** and for that the provider has allocated **3 public IP addresses**. For each IP the owner wants to have 3 different wireless/cable private networks with different bandwidths allocated to each.

Questions are:

1. Is there a piece of hardware that can do this setup
2. If this cannot be done with only one piece of hardware what would be a an alternate network design

Working scenario:

> They have an office connection (IP1) that provides basic connectivity to
>   e-mail, search, browsing. People visiting could have access to another
>   public wi-fi (IP2) with very low bandwidth. Occasionally they could
>   broadcast video and a camera could be plugged in the router by cable
>   and broadcast a video signal. This connection (IP3) should have the maximum
>   bandwidth, however if not used the bandwidth should be shared entirely
>   to the office connection (IP1).

Comment: You should edit your question to remove the request for recommendations since product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Q#1 is still asking for recommendations (I'm sure you don't want the literal yes/no answer) Q#2 is both "too broad" and "opinion bases" -- there are many ways to do this, none of them any more or less correct than any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NAT private networks to the public addresses. Business/enterprise-class routers can easily do this.

The rest of your question can be handled by a proper QoS configuration. QoS really needs to have a comprehensive policy defined, and it works best if traffic is marked as close to the source as possible (on your switches), and then you can set up queues, bandwidth restrictions, etc. where they are needed. Just understand that QoS will work well in your network, and for traffic exiting your network, but the Internet will not honor your QoS policies, and by the time you receive traffic from the Internet, the bandwidth has already been used (you have no real control over traffic coming from the Internet to your router).

Everything you want to do can be handled by many different business/enterprise-grade routers. You need to do some research to find the one you want.